# Swift / How to set addSubview to Subview?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to add a Subview on my googleAdBanner-Subview. (as a custom close UIButton).

If I add the UIButton as subview to self.view.addSubview(btn), it is working. But since it may take a while to load an Ad, sometimes the UIButton is visible even tho the googleAdBanner is still invisible.

If I add UIButton as subview of googleAdBanner, the UIButton will not be displayed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let googleAdBanner = GADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - 50,self.view.frame.size.width,50))

    googleAdBanner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xx"
    googleAdBanner.rootViewController = self
    googleAdBanner.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    self.view.addSubview(googleAdBanner)

    let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 25, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 25, 25))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    btn.setTitle("Click Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RootVC.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.tag = 1
    googleAdBanner.addSubview(btn)
}
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: make the your 'btn' like: `let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 25, 25))`
after adding that as subview to the banner, then adjust the button frame either by setting the CGrect or auto layout

Comment: @SiavashAlp so your solution is to create the button -> set button as subview -> and then change its frame? what's the difference?

Comment: okay. well for some reason your suggestion works. could you explain me why? where is the difference?

Comment: but i still have the problem, that the button appears before the ad... is there some chance to find out if the ad has been loaded?

Comment: when you add the Button to the banner view as a subview with  `self.view.frame.size.height - 50` y position, it based that on the Y of the super view which in this case the banner, so it would be end up of the screen. so normally what you do if you don't want to add your button or whatever in another subview (i.e not the main view) , you start of (0,0) to always be in origin of the super view, after adding it to the subview, then you could modified the bounds within the super view bounds

Comment: what it means is that you have started creating your button with `CGRectMake(0,5,50,50)` it would put the button in (0,5) of its superview which is the banner view.

Comment: got it and it's working. but i can't change the position. for some reason it stays at 0,5 even tho i change its parameters and like said, it's displayed before the (obviously clear-colored subview) displays an ad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122637/discussion-between-siavash-alp-and-david-seek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your 'btn' sth like: `let btn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, btnWidth, btnHeight))` after adding that as subview to the banner, then adjust the button frame either by setting the CGrect or auto layout